# Images as buttons google app maker

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm building a Backoffice and want the 1st page to resemble the google Apps dashboard (see image). Any idea how I can create large buttons that include a title, image and sub text?

[Google Apps Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA88r.png)

[Behaviour on mouseOver](https://indestat.tinytake.com/sf/MTg5Nzc5NF82MDY4MDY0)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best option from the layout perspective will be Grid widget with onClick handler for GridCell(select Cards style variant for mot prominent hover effect):

```js
// Cell onClick handler
app.showPage(app.pages.SomePage);
```

But the datasource for this thing will be the whole different story...